# Function inside loop closure issue

Tags: javascript, closures

i am really struggling to understand closures. I just wrote a little function to try and store multiple function in array indexes but they are undefined when i print them out.

Here is my code:

```
function x() {

    var arr = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        arr.push( (function(index) { console.log(index) } )(i) );
    }

    return arr;
}

var z = new x();

for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    console.log(z[j]); // Reads Undefined?
}
```

As far as i can see i am using an IIFE and passing in 'i' and using it as 'index' which should get me around the known closure scoping issue of printing out the last index constantly. But why are my array indexes undefined and not printing out the 'i'?

Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Your IIFE doesn't return anything, which means it is implicitly returning `undefined`. So you are pushing `undefined` into your array five times, leading to the result you see. Try returning the index from that function, eg: `console.log(index); return index;` instead.

Comment: Silly me :) thank you

Comment: Hopefully you'll see that the IIFE function is unnecessary for pushing the index to the array. It would only be useful if you were pushing a function that needed to keep reference to the current index.

Answer (score 3):

You don't return anything from your IIFE, so it implicitly returns `undefined` which is appended to the array. If you want to store the value of `index` you need to return it:

```
arr.push( (function(index) { console.log(index); return index; } )(i) );
```

Comment: Oh i see.. Thank you for the reply.